# -synctex=1 doesn't work

Tags: texmaker

I'm using texmaker, and to show the pdf file (internal), I used `-synctex=1` to show it in the position where i'm writing the code.

I worked pretty well for me before, but it has stopped working for 2 days. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to remove blank spaces in the path to the tex file.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, removing blank spaces does solve the TeXmaker to PDF direction, but not the converse. Would you have any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Sadly not John!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: check for non-regular characters in the file path and replace them with standard ones.

For example, to make the synchronization source-pdf with Synctex functionality in TeXMaker work for me i needed to remove a `ü` in the file-path, which is a german vowel.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I had the same issue. As I'm French, there was an accent mark ('é') in the file's path. I removed it and now it works. As for spaces in the file's path, they don't seem to be a problem.